# command line to put values separated by comma in separate lines

Tags: command-line, mac, terminal

I have a very big .txt file with 1748251 lines. Most lines have one value. Some lines have 2 or more values separated by comma.
What command help separate those values into different lines?

ie. input.txt

## rs1

## rs2

## rs3

## rs4,rs5,rs6

## rs7,rs8

## rs9

## rs10

I want the output.txt to be each in one line

## rs1

## rs2

## rs3

## rs4

## rs5

## rs6

## rs7

## rs8

## rs9

## rs10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Mac has it (I only have Linux, but a lot of the utilities are the same) you can use the "tr" command to translate "," to newline with a command like

```
tr "," "\n" < input.txt > output.txt
```